# Unable to browse in all browsers to all sites after running threaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a weird problem and I am not sure where is it coming from.
Started last night when I started my application.

I have the following code:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
WebRequest req = (WebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://" + server + url + action);
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
try
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
        TestInfo.CheckMsg retMsg;

        // individual Test
        retMsg = indFunc(req.RequestUri.ToString(), response);
        printMessage(retMsg, req, res, startTime);

        if (retMsg.SeverityLevel > TestInfo.CheckMsg.Severity.Warning)
            return;

        // group Test
        retMsg = groupFunc(relatedGroup, req.RequestUri.ToString(), response);
        printMessage(retMsg, req, res, startTime);

        if (retMsg.SeverityLevel > TestInfo.CheckMsg.Severity.Warning)
            return;

        // common Test
        retMsg = commonFunc(req.RequestUri.ToString(), response);
        printMessage(retMsg, req, res, startTime);

        if (retMsg.SeverityLevel > TestInfo.CheckMsg.Severity.Warning)
            return;

        reader.Close();
    };
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION WAS THROWN!!!!! " + e.Message);
}
finally
{
    res.Close();
}
```

This function runs on several threads.
After several application debugging this code fails to connect claiming UNDERLYING CONNECTION WAS CLOSED.
when trying to browse in my computer (WIN XP) in all browsers to all sites I get either blank page or in chrome I get that the response from the server was empty.

Http only is screwed while other TCP connections work!

So I guess the problem might be in my code (maybe something is not released???)

Let me know what do you think of the code.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _'all browsers to all sites ... blank page'_? A lot of this question is nonsensical but I don't know where to start to edit it.

Comment: I know it doesnt make sense! DNS works, I get HTTP redirects ok, but even google.com, yahoo.com won't load - chrome is the only one who says it got EMPTY RESPONSE from the server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I do see wrong is that you need to move

```
 WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
```

Into your try block bc it can throw an exception[(MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx)). I would also add a null check to:

```
 if(res != null){
   res.Close()
 }
```